# Facebook SDK v4 and Parse SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to implement facebook login/signup methods with parse on my app but since the v4 update i haven't been able to. I followed the exact steps provided by both Parse and Facebook but something is not working. I know that Parse SDK contains FacebookUtilsV4.framework but their functions are not working. Has anyone been able to get this working after the V4 update?

Comment: Define 'not working'. What test scenarios, what results, what log output.

Comment: I actually get this error: [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/ephdua.png[/IMG]
I'm new to iOS coding so I really don't know what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PFLoginViewController` that is part of the Parse UI framework now also supports FB login with SKD v4. [See source code on GitHub.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/087a901e74c0ed2a107af7ce3802daef3038440b/ParseUI/Classes/LogInViewController/PFLogInViewController.m#L317-L327)

I'm using it with Parse 1.7.1, so v4 support is definitely working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at  https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-signup/iOS , it states that `Parse is compatible with version 3.2 of the Facebook iOS SDK.`

I was looking for a solution for android development as well when I came across this sentence, which is weird because Parse did include in the SDK docs (https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html) stating that `Warning: This class supports official Facebook iOS SDK v4.0+ and is available only on iOS.`

If Parse sees this question, please either renew the guide or the tutorial with some samples on how to integrate facebook login using the newest SDK.

EDIT: For now, I think it is safe to either use the v3.x Facebook SDK or just follow Facebook's tutorial on how to use their v4.x SDK. But I m not sure if you can integrate that with `ParseUser` when the user logs in using his/her facebook if you use v4.x

Comment: Yes I saw that when i was trying to implement it. The thing is that I was following all the steps and then getting the same error in the end. I will look again on the tutorials and try to do it. I just wanted to know if anyone was successful doing this or the problem was me. I'm new to iOS programming, 2 weeks only, so sorry for causing any disturbs!
Thanks!

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/ephdua.png[/IMG]

This is the error i get

Comment: I have been successfully integrate fb login in android by using fb sdk v3.2 actually. It might be the same case as in iOS.. Go look at the Parse-UI sample codes and you should be able to do it. Good luck

Comment: But where can you actually download the PFFacebookUtils class? I can't find it.;